# Saving and querying rows by date intervals

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table of `measurements` that has the following structure:

`| id | value1 | value2 | value3| value4 | taken_at |`

Where the `value` attributes are numeric values, and the `taken_at` attribute is a datetime value that refers to the time when the measurement was taken.

The application that uses this database will need later the average of the measurements in a time interval. For example, it will need:

- The average of the measurements of the past month.
- The average of the measurements of the last 3 weeks
- The average of the measurements of this year.

Because I don't want to recalculate the averages every time, I was thinking in calculate it one time and then saving it in a table of `averages` with the following structure:

`| id | value1 | value2 | value 3 | value4 | begin | end |`

Where every `valuei` represents the average of all the `valuei` from the `measurements` table that were taken between the `begin`and `end` datetimes. This way I can save the average between every arbitrary interval. The problem with this schema is that I don't know how to make the queries of the type "give me the average of the past 3 months" or "give me all the averages that have a yearly interval".

How can I make such queries with this structure? Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

So you should be able to join the table on itself and do this for at least the three month. It may get big with anything greater than that

Try

```
 Select a.id, average(a.value1,b.value1,c.value1), 
    average(a.value2,b.value2,c.value2)etc...  a.taken_at
    from measurements a, measurements b, measurements c
    where a.taken_at =b.taken_at+1
    and b.taken_at=c.taken_at+1
    Group By id,a.taken_at
```

This would give you a three month average ending at the returned taken at date. Alternatively you could just do

```
   Select id, average(value1), average(value2)...
      from measurements 
      where taken at between(x,y)
      Group by id
```

But that just gives you one row of custom interval (x,y) averages
Let me know if that helps or not.